# How to perform addition to number rather than appending to end in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Trying to update a table in ASP.net MVC with a Linq query. It works fine in terms of actually doing the update, but I can't figure out how to mathematically update it. For example, the Printer Credit Fund was set to "50", added 12 to it then sets it "5012" as opposed to "62". The following is the code that is doing the update:

```
tblOption fund = (
                    from n in db.tblOptions
                    where n.ID == 1
                    select n).First();
                fund.PrinterCreditFund = fund.PrinterCreditFund + tblPrinterCredit.Money;
```

We're using Entity Framework if that makes any sort of a difference.

Any tips towards the right direction of doing a mathematical update rather than appending the value would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: `PrinterCreditFund ` or `Money` seem to be a string instead of a numeric type. That's the problem to fix.

Comment: Can you add `tblOption` class code?

Comment: It would worry me that these columns on tblOptions appear to be strings in the database. If they have currency values in them (which their names suggest) then they should be typed correctly for that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it. Convert `fund.PrinterCreditFund` and `tblPrinterCredit.Money` to using `Convert.ToInt32()` and also make sure `fund.PrinterCreditFund` is also `int` type

```
tblOption fund = (
                    from n in db.tblOptions
                    where n.ID == 1
                    select n).First();
                fund.PrinterCreditFund = Convert.ToInt32( fund.PrinterCreditFund) + Convert.ToInt32( tblPrinterCredit.Money);
```

Comment: It would bother me more that they aren't already numeric types on tblOptions given the column names. In addition `Int32` won't be the right time to use for currency values - any decimal places will be broken.

Comment: It's upto user about that. He can convert it to decimal too. I saw integers in OP's question so I've used `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: Thanks for that Rahul :).

@JonEgerton nothing to do with me, the database was there before I joined, had zero involvement in the design of the database

Comment: @JonEgerton Yep! Makes the project that little bit more interesting though, if not for the extra time things take

Answer (score 0):

I guess that either `Money` is a `string`. Then the `+` operator concats them instead of summing the values. So both must be a numeric type, for example `int`:

```
fund.PrinterCreditFund = fund.PrinterCreditFund + int.Parse(tblPrinterCredit.Money);
```

Of course it would be better to not store a number as string in the first place.